# spring-boot MongoDB find all return empty, how to troubleshoot it?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

I have a simple spring-boot project for accessing items in a MongoDB:

```
@Autowired
private ItemRepository itemRepositoryDAO;
 ...
itemRepositoryDAO.findAll();
```

and in ItemRepository.java:

```
 .... 
 @Repository
 public interface ItemRepository extends MongoRepository<Item, String> {

 }
```

However findAll return always empty.
If I connect to MongoDB from the shell, I can verify I have items.
How can I troubleshoot this? MongoDB and spring are running inside docker.

Not much helpful logging.

What can I do?

Comment: 1, Check what db instance you are connecting to. 2, what query is being triggered from the app, you can find it in the debug logs, 3. Check if Item schema is same as the item document schema in mongo db.

Comment: @ardhani I managed to activate logging, wrong collection name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below properties in `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=trace
```

This should give more details about what SQL query is being executed against the DB.

Edit:

Turns out that a wrong collection name was being used in query.

Comment: hmmm added, deployed, and checked on the docker image, but I still don't see any logging. Is there some loggers to add to log4j2.xml?

Comment: I added <Logger name="org.hibernate" ...and <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL"... to log4j2.xml and now I see it. Missing "s" in the collection name...great! thks